# Backbone Marionette and RequireJS

Tags: backbone.js, controller, requirejs, marionette, router

I am trying to set up a new application using Backbone.Marionette and RequireJS. I am following along with [enzo's guide](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/06/02/routing-controlling-with-marionettejs/) to set up my routers and controllers but am getting the following error- "Undefined is not a function" when trying to instantiate the controller.

```
require( ['marionette', './assets/js/router', './assets/js/routeController'], function (Marionette, Router, routeController)  {  

    var MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    var controller = new routeController({});
```

And if I hover over routeController in the function paramater is shows as "undefined."

What am I doing wrong? This is driving me insane.

Edit: The routeController file is as follows-

```
define(["marionette"], function (Marionette) {

   var Controller = Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize : function(options) {

     },
    start: function() {

    },

     home :  function () {
        alert('Hello, welcome home!');
    },
});

return Controller;
```

});

Comment: what does your routeController file look like?

Comment: @ne8il I have updated my post with the routeController code, which is identical to the code listed on the guide I linked.

Comment: You don't need to do `Backbone.Marionette` if your defining Marionette as an AMD module, just use `Marionette.*`

Comment: @KyleNeedham Regardless of how I define Marionette, I still get an error "Cannot read property 'Controller' of undefined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a `null` when requesting a module from RequireJS, there are two typical possibilities:

1)  The module being required in isn't returning something

Is `Controller` non-null in `routeController.js`?  Throw a debugger in there to make sure.

2)  There is a circular dependency somewhere

It's easy enough to create a circular dependency somewhere in your modules.  Doesn't look like that's the case here, but could happen if `router.js` is doing something funky.